# Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'project.playing' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

> error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'project.playing' doesn't exist   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)

In eclipse using maven project trying to create a table(playing) in the existind mysql databse(project) using hibernate . 
entity class code:

```
package com.rj.hibtry.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "playing")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    int userId;

    @Column(name = "username")
    String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    String lastName;


    public Users(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

main method code:

```
package com.rj.hibtry;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.rj.hibtry.entity.Users;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          SessionFactory factory=new Configuration()
                  .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                  .addAnnotatedClass(Users.class)
                  .buildSessionFactory();
          Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();
          try {
              // Create object of entity class type
              Users user = new Users("lj", "password", "firstName", "lastName");
              // Start transaction
              session.beginTransaction();
              // Perform operation
              session.save(user);
              // Commit the transaction 
              session.getTransaction().commit();
              System.out.println("Row added!");


        } finally {
            session.close();
            factory.close();
        }


      }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Connection settings -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
              <!-- Sample MySQL URL provided  -->  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Show SQL on console -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>



        <!--Setting Session context model -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Do the logs show any SQL that it's trying to run?

Comment: Apr
Hibernate: drop table if exists playing
Apr 25, 2020 12:18:12 PM [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@78a515e4] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table playing (user_id integer not null, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (user_id)) type=MyISAM

Comment: Hibernate: insert into playing (first_name, last_name, password, username, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) Apr 25, 2020 12:18:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02 Apr 25, 2020 12:18:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR: Table 'project.playing' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

People who are using MySQL above 4.0 version they need to change the dialect in the configuration file. **"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"** will work till version 4.0, above that you need to use **"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"**